# Json file : create table or dataframe by using python pyspark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file that have this type of schema :

[image]

and trying to create a table or dataframe base on them.
Before that, have managed to upload the file using this script :

```
first_row_is_header = "true"
infer_schema = "true"
delimiter = ":"
df4 = spark.read.option("multiLine","true") \
.option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
.option("sep", delimiter) \
.json ("/FileStore/tables/Ca_sect2.json")
```

End result become like this :

[image]

How do I convert the result below into table form? Have tried several types of scripts like `dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView`, but keep on failing to get the result.
Grateful for some help, as have been trying for 2 days.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to explode the array structure of `developerSales`:

```
df.withColumn("sales", explode(col("developerSales")))\
  .select(col("developer"), col("sales.*"))\
  .show()
```